# iOS App - How can I change the launch image from an external source?

Tags: ios, launchimage

When an iOS app starts, it takes the launch image from a folder called `Images.xcassets`. I want to know how can I change the starting image to one that comes from a server.

Answer (score 1):

It's **not possible** to use a launch image provided from an external source. You should bundle every element (launch image/launch screen) with your application.

Comment: Is there a way to make the launch image different every time

Comment: @OldChicken Since you can't run code in the launch screen's controller, there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't Launch Image change dynamically.
But you can show the image from server in a custom view controller before show your main interface, lots of software does this, of course you can put video or ads on it.

According to apple user interaction guide, launch image will be load at first time you run this app. So it's impossible to change it dynamically.

You only can set multiply images for each languages, but still, iOS will load one of them and won't change anymore.

Hope this can help you! :)

Comment: That's what you're talking about. My app already has it. But the product manager wants to configure the launch image automatically,Unfortunately, I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: @OldChicken Yep, I've add document instruction in my answer. Apple don't want launch view to be interactive.

Answer (score 0):

Use a blank view in your LaunchScreen.storyboard - then in your Initial view controller, get your image from your server.

Keep in mind - if the device does not have internet service, or has particularly slow service, your app will look like it is not doing anything... so you should at least have some sort of "fall-back" screen.